# Has Jinx committed similar crimes in the games?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, arcane

Based on the sources that I have read, in the games Jinx is known for a variety of, if not harmless crimes, at least largely non-lethal ones. For instance, according to the wiki, her misdeeds include:

- Crashing a wedding and blowing up the cake. Not exactly harmless, but no one appears to have been hurt worse than being burnt by soup.
- Blocking the streets with a stampede of animals.
- Disrupting trade by placing flame chompers on the bridges.
- Robbing and blowing up strongboxes in the treasury.

As her character biography says, these actions are "criminally dangerous pranks" at most.

By contrast, in the show (just in the first season) she has quite intentionally killed a half-dozen enforcers in a bombing, killed dozens of enforcers in another bombing (as well as shooting one or two of them), and

> seems on track to kill many more people with her rocket launcher at the end of the season.

Has the game version of Jinx ever committed crimes that caused a loss of life similar to what is seen on the show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% on the provenance of this wanted poster, but it does include "murder ... murder again ... more murders" among her offenses:

[image: Wanted poster for Jinx] (click to enlarge)

Also, since the series is a prequel, it could be that these charges relate to her actions in the series.